# scanf returns non 0 value againt wrong input

Tags: c

if i input "1k"(or any number followed by letters) into scanf at this configuration i still get a true (non 0) returned from the function, is there any way to explicitly return false if anything but integers are present?
basically i wanna know if my string is only numbers or not

p.s. legal switch checks if my input is one of a few given options

```
void clearBuffer() {
    while (getchar() != '\n') {}
}

int getChoice(){
    int choice = 0;


    //clearBuffer();

    while (scanf("%d",&choice)!=0 ||!legalSwitch(choice))
    {
        clearBuffer();
        printf("\nWrong choice, please choose an integer between 1 to 3: ");


    }
}
```

Comment: Since `scanf` is pretty limited, you will probably need to rely on stuff from `ctype.h`. Writing a strict or complex parser, usually doesn't involve `scanf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding a `getchar()!='\n'` into the while loop condition seemed to solve my issue, however im 90% certain this isnt the way to go but this will have to do for now

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read an entire line using [fgets](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) (always check the return value), then use `if (sscanf(line, "%d%n", &choice, &size) >= 1 && size == strlen(line))` (see also [sscanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html)).

Alternatively, instead of *sscanf* you can use [strtoul](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoul.3.html) or [strtoull](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoull.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` format specifier reads digits until it encounters a non-digit.  Whether that non-digit is whitespace or some other character doesn't matter.

What you can do instead is use `fgets` to read a full line of text, then use `strtol` to parse the value, using the `endptr` parameter to see where parsing stopped.  If it points to anything other than a newline or a null byte, you know there were extra characters entered.

```
char line[100];
fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
char *p;
long x = strtol(line, &p, 10);
if (*p != '\n' && *p != 0) {
    printf("not an integer\n");
} else if (errno != 0) {
    printf("value out of range\n");
}
```

Comment: i did not know the specifier worked that way!
however, is there a way to avoid using a set size array for this? we were not explicitly told to avoid it but were told its best to
edit: to clarify, the biggest input here *should* be a single digit, but if someone inputs something thats > 100, will i get issues or is there a way to dump the excess and not have it take memory space?

Comment: @Flyleaf If there are more characters to read than what the buffer can hold, it will read as much as it can.  Because `fgets` will include the newline character if there's room for it, you'll know if there are more characters to read if the last character in the string isn't a newline (i.e. `'\n'`).